# Find if node has siblings using simplexml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, siblings

I am try to find if a certain node has siblings, and if it does, I would like to know what those siblings are.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to select a node's siblings, you have to use the corresponding XPath axe. Here is how to select all a node's siblings (ignoring the node itself)

```
$siblings = $node->xpath('preceding-sibling::* | following-sibling::*');
```

That's all you have to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think using xpath is your best bet here:

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<document>
 <title>Forty What?</title>
 <from>Joe</from>
 <to>Jane</to>
 <body>
  I know that's the answer -- but what's the question?
 </body>
</document>
XML;

function get_all_siblings(SimpleXMLElement $node)
{
  return $node->xpath('preceding-sibling::* | following-sibling::*');
}

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

foreach (get_all_siblings($xml->to) as $e)
  echo $e->getName()."\n";    
?>
```

Results in:

```
title
from
body
```

Comment: Because of the way SimpleXML works, you cannot filter the context node using `($node != $e)` as this comparison will always be true, even when both variables represent the same node.

Comment: I don't use SimpleXML enough to have realized that... I've updated my code with different xpath syntax (which I see you've already posted anyway) that makes the function basically irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
$xmlNode = $xml->xpath('root/yourNodeName');
$nodeCount = count($xmlNode);
```

Not sure if this is still useful to you